# Working on unrelated tasks

Tags: europe, software-engineering

I've recently moved abroad for work since there isn't any similar position in my home country. However the tasks I've been given have only insignificant (to me) overlap with my position at the company. (Fwiw those tasks aren't small, they can take a few months to complete). Since the whole point of me moving abroad is to do what I would like this has taken a significant toll on me. My question is what should I do in this situation? Should I complain to someone? Should I just suck it up?

Comment: Is anyone at the company working on tasks that overlap with your position?

Comment: When you applied for the job, did you ask what sort of tasks you would be doing? Did you ask if the company had a need for those kinds of tasks?

Comment: If the job was presented as something different from what it has become, you should bring that up with your boss. If your boss is somehow a factor in creating that situation (such that you don't feel comfortable bringing it up), you _might_ (big emphasis) try going to their boss (your skip-level boss), but this can create new, larger problems for you if you aren't careful. Anyway, this kind of thing happens all the time, "bait and switch" basically, where someone joins a team and then gets something dumped upon them that they never would have agreed to.

Answer (score 2):

> Should I complain to someone?

You should certainly speak to your supervisor.  A calm discussion that focuses on facts is more likely to be productive that a complaint though.

If the work you have been given is in scope for your role (e.g. a software engineer being asked to work with one framework but preferring another), you should probably only remind your boss of your strong interest in your preferred area.

If the work you have been given is out of scope for your role (e.g. an engineer being asked to paint the building) you should mention that this is outside your expected duties and ask how quickly you'll move to your expected duties.

In either of these cases, be prepared for the possibility that none of your preferred work is available now.  If you start with a calm conversation, you can decide whether to give an ultimatum about moving role, to start job hunting or to suck it up, keeping your salary.  If you start by complaining, demanding work that is not available, you're effectively jumping straight to an ultimatum without knowing whether this can possibly be met.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is what should I do in this situation?

You should find a new job that would allow you to do what you would like.

Then you should give your notice, work out your notice period, and leave this job.